# Research partner switching authorship before publishing to Arxiv?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, authorship, collaboration, arxiv

We’re currently publishing a preview of a paper we’ve just gotten accepted to a conference and of the five of us, one member started an Arxiv submission application first. This means that the rest of us were not able to submit an application in lieu of his, even though he did not have the final version of the paper. In submitting the work to Arxiv, he actually switched the originally alphabetical authorship so that his name went first.

How can you force someone to remove their submission? We keep texting him, but he is ignoring us, and if this continues, this falsely authored version will be what is published and out there, but different from the legitimate version of the paper.

Answer (score 13):

**Make sure this is actually malicious.  If so Contact arXiv.**

For co-authored papers every author should be an owner of the paper. Usually, the person who submitted the paper gives the other authors the password. It sounds like that will be problematic in this case, but you can [claim ownership](https://arxiv.org/help/authority) of your paper without the password through the arXiv system.  (This will require manual intervention from someone at arXiv.)

On the contact form there you should probably explain exactly the situation.  They are going to be the only ones who can properly address and sort through what is going on.

Needless to say, you should make absolutely sure that this rogue coauthor is intending to do this and it is not some sort of mistake.  It seems like extremely odd behavior since the paper is already submitted with the correct authorship, so it's quite easy to prove he has changed the order.  Also, once you bring this to the arXiv's attention it could have consequences for this coauthor, such as getting banned from submitting papers, etc, so make sure the act really is malicious before doing this.

Comment: +1 for "claim ownership", though I think it can be done with less drama.  The Claim Ownership form just asks you to list the paper(s) in question, there's not even any space for comments or explanation.  So the OP (or another coauthor with an established arXiv account) can simply try to claim the paper, without involving the arXiv moderators in the gory details.  If successful, OP gets the paper password, which can then be used to upload a corrected manuscript and/or edit the metadata, and all is well unless the rogue coauthor tries to object.

Comment: In that case, or if the moderators don't grant ownership to the OP, then OP can explain the situation to them.  But this has the advantage that if it is simply a mistake on the part of the rogue author, it corrects it without accusing them of anything.  Likewise, even if it was intentional, it lets the rogue author save face by saying it was a mistake and thanking OP for fixing it.

Answer (score 5):

I see two possible ways:

- Wait until the “real” paper is published and contact the ArXiv.
- Try to obtain the paper password. Every author gets such a password after a successfull ArXiv submission to share with their coauthors. One function is that coauthors can officially register themselves as authors; the other one is that authors can update the paper, including the order of authors.

Two notes:

- The situation you describe is ripe with escalation. I suggest by all means to carify the situation before acting, as the latter has a high potential to exacerbate matters.
- I am not aware of any case where ArXiv author order matters in lieu of the order on the actual paper. The main incentive I would have to fix such things is to avoid confusion, as papers are often identified by their author order.